# how to plot a line graph by reading the values from database (sql) in vb.net?

Tags: sql, vb.net, mschart

i'm using vb.net and sql as my database. 
how i'm going to plot a line graph ? by using this sql statement

my X axis will be the range value from Time_stamp that will be key-in by user which i assign that as =  from 6/24/2013 8:38:00 AM to 6/24/2013 8:38:23 AM
and my Y axis will be BB_ID that will key-in by user and i assign that as = 3100

this is my general code :

```
    Dim connectionString As String = "server='abc'; user id='***'; password='***'; Database='***'"
    Dim sqlConnection As SqlClient.SqlConnection = New SqlClient.SqlConnection(connectionString)

    sqlConnection.Open()

    Dim queryString As String = "SELECT Time_stamp, BB_ID, Status, " & _
    "(CASE WHEN Status = 'R' THEN 0 WHEN status = 'O' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END) AS newstatus"& _
    "FROM(dbo.rawdata)" & _
    "WHERE (BB_ID = '3100') AND (Time_stamp >= '6/24/2013 8:38:00 AM') AND (Time_stamp <= '6/24/2013 8:38:23 AM')"

    Chart1.Series("line_area").Points.AddXY("3100", "10")
    Chart1.Series("line_area").Points.AddXY("3100", "8")
    Chart1.Series("line_area").ChartType = System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Line

    sqlConnection.Close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to change to ZedGraph. MSChart works fine in this case too. You have created a query string, but you are not querying the database.

```
string connectionString =   // your connection string
string queryString =        // your query string

// Create a database connection object using the connection string    
SQLConnection sqlConnection =  // your connection object

// Create a database command on the connection using query    
SQLCommand  sqlCommand = // your command

sqlConnection .Open();

// set chart data source - the data source must implement IEnumerable
chart1.DataSource = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);

// Set series members names for the X and Y values 
chart1.Series["line_area"].XValueMember = "Time_stamp"; // the column you want on X axis
chart1.Series["line_area"].YValueMembers = "BB_ID"; // the column you want on Y axis

// Data bind to the selected data source
chart1.DataBind();
```

In your code

```
Chart1.Series("line_area").Points.AddXY("3100", "10")
Chart1.Series("line_area").Points.AddXY("3100", "8")
```

you are just adding two points to the chart, thats all, the data from the database is not connected to the chart at all.